# what possible callback triggers are available for a kivy accordion item change?

Tags: accordion, kivy

in my app I dynamically build an Accordion widget and keep an index list :

```
            acc_panel = self.ids.acc_panel
            tpitem = string.Template('''
AccordionItem:
    id: '$acc_id'
    title: '$acc_title'
    font_name: 'Roboto'
    min_space: 30
    RstDocument:
        background_color: 1, 1, 1, 1
        source: '$rstdoc'
            ''')

            for idx in range(0, self.totevents):
                event = str(idx + 1)
                acc_id = 'acc_' + event
                evidx = 'Event' + event + ':'
                rstdoc = qglobals.PROJDIR + tempInstrData[evidx]['RstDoc:']
                acc_title = str(tempInstrData[evidx]['Instruction:'])

                new_acc = tpitem.substitute(vars())
                acc = Builder.load_string(new_acc)
                acc_panel.add_widget(acc)

            n = len(acc_panel.children)
            for i in range (0,n):
                acc_panel.children[i].collapse = True
                acclabel[i+1] = n-1-i
            acc_panel.children[n-1].collapse = False
            accactive = 1
            activeEvent = 1
            self.change_accitem()
```

and in the related kv file I have:

```
    Accordion:
        id: acc_panel
        orientation: 'vertical'
        min_space: 30
        font_name: 'Roboto'
```

Now I want to add some action on an AccordionItem change by binding the new item to a callback function. I have tried to use the attribute: on_collapse but that one doesn't work. What are the possibilities here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AccordionItem` has a property called `collapse`. This is what you bind to:

```
ai = AccordionItem()
ai.bind(collapse=my_callback)
```

The event handlers automatically called within a class are called `on_<property_name>`, but you `bind` to `<property_name>`. (Also see [properties and events](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html#observe-using-bind).)

Comment: Hi zeeMonkeez, thanks for your clarification. However, I am still struggling. So if acc_panel holds the accordion widget (acc_panel.add_widget(acc), it's  children are the AccordionItems. Is that correct? When I then bind all these children in a loop to my callback: acc_panel.children[idx].bind(collapse=self.do_print), I expect that everytime I click on the title of an accordionitem, the respective title will be printed. But this happens only for the first accordionitem. What am I missing....?

Comment: Oops, made a typo in the loop. Above is indeed the case and works as a charm now. Thanks again.